# Using the iOS SoundCloud API with ARC

Tags: ios, xcode5, automatic-ref-counting, soundcloud, git-submodules

Hi I am trying to implement the sound cloud API from the sound cloud tutorial for iOS (https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart)

I am having trouble with ARC. It seems like OAUTH2 uses ARC but the sound cloud API does not. Is there anyone who has gone through this process and can help me through this?

I feel the tutorial is missing some crucial steps

Comment: When I download the submodules, I have five of them, and they call retain and release and autorelease

Answer (score 0):

in build settings, specific which source files should ignore arc

[How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)